# Can you prevent a command from going into the bash shell command history?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Is there a way to prevent a command from being added to the bash shell's command history?

I would like to be able to prevent certain "dangerous" commands from being added to the history, such as "`rm -rf ~/some/dir`", so that it is not accessible to me by pressing the up-arrow to reach previous commands.  In this way, it would not be possible to accidentally repeat one of these commands.

The reason I ask is that I use the up arrow a lot to access previous commands in the shell history, and have often caught myself about to hit enter on what I **thought** was the correct command, only to realise that I was about to do something stupid/annoying/dangerous.  I don't like the idea of `rm`s etc floating around in my shell history, waiting for me to step on them!

(Note: I am aware that one can set up patterns in HISTIGNORE, but what would be nice is something one can apply on a per-command basis, which would become good a habit.  Unless there is a clever way to achieve this using HISTIGNORE that I have missed?)

Comment: As per the deleted answer, it's worth using control-R for reverse history type-ahead search, instead of the up arrow. This helps reduce the chances of such mistakes, though it's still worth suppressing things from history.

Comment: No sure how preventing `rm -rf ~/some/dir` from running again would cause a problem.  It was already deleted!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

On newer Bash Versions you could simply add a space at the beginning of your command. :)
If it doesn't work by default, add [ \t]* to HISTIGNORE. (As mentioned in the comments. thx)

Comment: If it doesn't work by default, add [ \t]* to HISTIGNORE.

Answer (score 46):

Add ***ignorespace*** to your **HISTCONTROL** environment variable. Then any command line that begins with a space won't be entered into your history.

Comment: Multiple HISTCONTROL options can be set by separating them with colons, like: export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace