# When using the terminal history, can I force confirmation when executing dangerous commands from my history?

Tags: bash, shell

My terminal workflow involves a lot of navigating the bash history with `UP`,  `UP`, `RETURN`. Occasionally I misremember or mistype the number of `UP`'s and invoke the wrong command. Sometimes it can be a bit painful (`git clone`) or quite painful (`git push`). One day, I'm sure I will do something very painful.

I find myself avoiding certain useful but potentially dangerous commands because of this. I can [avoid adding these commands to my history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640403/can-you-prevent-a-command-from-going-into-the-bash-shell-command-history), but I like my history.

**I would like to blacklist certain commands (or regexp test), so if I invoke them using my history they will require confirmation before executing:**

```
$ git status
$ rm -rf node_modules # typed - no confirmation
$ rm -rf node_modules # UP, RETURN - confirmation
Blacklisted command - Are you sure? (yes/no)?
```

Comment: Only from history? No -- at execution time, there are no flags available to indicate whether a command was retrieved from history or executed directly, and thus no way to execute conditional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Functions as Command Wrappers

The shell doesn't directly support this feature, in part because a command is stored in history *before* it is executed. However, you can largely fake it by wrapping your "dangerous" commands in functions that take precedence over the real commands. For example:

```
rm () {
    local regex='[Yy]'
    if history |  sed '$d' | pcregrep -q "^\s+\d+\s+${FUNCNAME} $*"; then
        read -p 'Are you sure? '
        [[ "$REPLY" =~ $regex ]] || return 1
    fi
    command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"
}
```

The secret sauce is the sed command that strips out the *current* command that's just been stored in history. Without that, grep would *always* find the command in the history.

### Caveats

1. Note the requirement for a grep compiled with PCRE support. You will need to adjust the regular expression if you don't have pcregrep or egrep compiled with PCRE support.
2. You might also have to adjust quoting or use eval if word splitting doesn't happen the way you think it should, but it worked fine for me in casual testing. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Nice, it also works for me. All I had to do on OSX El Capitan 10.11 was to add PCRE support (`brew install pcre`)

Comment: I think you can replace that whole pipeline with `history -p !?${FUNCNAME} $*?:q 2> /dev/null`.