# Bash History Scope

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos

Defined in .bashrc

```
function gitpullsite(){
    echo "Enter GIT username";
    read gituname;
    echo "Enter GIT password";
    read -s gitpword;
    giturl=https://$gituname:$gitpword@github.com/whateveruser/whateverrepo.git
    repopath=/home/whateveruser/html/whateverrepo/;
    sudo rm -r $repopath;
    sudo git clone $giturl $repopath;
}
```

and then run in terminal `gitpullsite` I want to remove `gituname` and `gitpword` from history but I cannot find such entries in history anywhere. I have no process in place to remove such entries so where is this history stored ? Is it ignored as within the scope of the function and not the shell ?

What I don't want is an unknown trail of usernames and passwords stored somewhere I don't know about - an obvious security issue should a system be compromised.

The aim is to add further different 'nested' repos but the user only needs to enter credentials once.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but the bash history will typically be stored in `~/.bash_history`. It will save commands only, not what is input in response to `read`.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to confirm, that commands within a function are not stored, merely the call to the function - unfortunately I was not allow to tag with '.bash_history'

Comment: Not only will it not save the passwords, it will actually only save the command issued directly, i.e. `gitpullsite`.

Comment: If you wanted to know whether lines which are read by `read` are stored in bash history, why didn't you ask that question clearly, even in the title of your question? (For example, "does the bash read builtin store what is read in the history?" or some such.) The answer is "no".

Comment: @Orange: It won't even do that, since `gitpullsite` was not entered by the user in a command prompt. Shell commands executed in functions are never stored in the history; shell commands executed from a script file are only stored in the history if in response to an explicit (and unusual) bash option.

Comment: Thanks so far, both good info and likely answers, sorry if the title seems vague but thought would be more concise, followed immediately with what is run from where with code (eg the function run from .bashrc). Also wondered if the inner sudo meant it was stored elsewhere (though I read it does not).

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com, since it's about using the Unix shell, not really about programming.

Comment: Why are you cloning repos as root?  That is a security disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try https://github.com/dvorka/hstr which, in addition to history management i.e. **deleting particular command(s) from history**, allows for "suggest box style" filtering.

[image]

It can be easily [bound](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) to <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl-s</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to not log part of your commands at all.

Multiple ways to do so :

*1*
To stop logging bash history is:

```
set +o history
```

and to reset, that is to start logging again:

```
set -o history
```

*2*
You can also use add ignorespace to your HISTCONTROL environment variable. Then any command line that begins with a space won't be entered into your history.

[methods for avoiding bash history logging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84596/methods-for-avoiding-bash-history-logging)

[Can you prevent a command from going into the bash shell command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640403/can-you-prevent-a-command-from-going-into-the-bash-shell-command-history)